# How to use a char value in table as a new table name

Tags: sql, macros

I have a table that stores a list of char values. I want to use the value as my new  table name...
For example,
column tbl_name has values:
table01
table02
table03

And table01-table03 are actual tables stored in my database. How can I refer to it directly?

For code like this: 
select * from table01
where salary>1000
;

Is it possible to replace "table01" as a piece of code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table_name varchar(25) = 'table01'
exec('select * from '+@table_name+' where salary > 1000')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic query for this.

```
 Declare @SqlQuery nvarchar(max)

Set @SqlQuery=’Select * from ’


// your logic here for getting table name
```

Suppose, you stored your table name into a temp variable named as @temp

Now, append your @SqlQuery variable as

```
@ SqlQuery= @SqlQuery+@temp +’  where salary>1000’
```

Finallt, execute your query as:

```
Exec (@SqlQuery)
```